# Can I bring a growler of beer in my checked bag?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, food-and-drink

I want to bring a growler of beer on my checked bag (not on-board). Growlers are generally 64 oz. [According to Delta](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/before-your-trip/restricted-items.html), I can bring alcohol that has been purchased after going through a security checkpoint, but doesn't say I can't bring it from outside on my checked bag.

I also know that there are drastic pressure changes for baggage on the plane. I don't want the growler to be a hazard, and I especially don't want it to explode all over my stuff.

[According to the TSA website](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=beer), it *should* be okay, but I'm still concerned.

Does anyone have experience traveling with growlers or other large glass containers of carbonated drink?

I am flying from Michigan to New Mexico, using Delta Airlines.

Update: I put it on my checked bag. I wrapped it in towels and stuffed it into my impromptu flimsy fabric bag after my suitcase's zipper broke the night before. The growler was completely fine, didn't leak and definitely didn't explode.

Comment: If it helps, I've taken lots of beer on planes and it has always been fine (the in-laws love Belgian beer!). News papers and socks help to keep it secure. Put an extra plastic bag around it in case it does go wrong (unlikely).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same page you linked to states:

> If the alcohol is purchased before going through the security checkpoint, our [security rules](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/check-in/security.html) apply for carry-on or checked baggage.

Which means you *must* pack the growler in your checked luggage, as it's over 100 mL.

There's no significant concern about it exploding. Remember that the cargo hold is [pressurized](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22604/3221) the same as the passenger cabin.